# error in algorithm for making a list of permutations of 123

Tags: python, algorithm

i want to have a list of permutation of 123 . when i run this code it says:

```
TypeError: NoneType object is not an iterator
```

when i run my algorithm with 'next' it works fine. but this way i get error. any help?

```
n = int(input())

elements = str(input())

elements = elements.split()

type(elements) == type([])

def factor(elements, i , n):

    if i == n - 1:
        return elements
    else:
        for j in range(i, n):
            elements[i], elements[j] = elements[j], elements[i]
            factor(elements, i + 1 , n)
            elements[i], elements[j] = elements[j], elements[i]

list = []

list = factor(elements, 0, n)

list = sorted(list) #error is for this part of code


while True :
    if list == [] : break
    else:
        print(list[0])
        list.pop(0)
```

when i use algorithm in this form it works fine :

```
def perm(n, i):
    if i == len(n) - 1:
        print(n)
    else:
        for j in range(i, len(n)):
            n[i], n[j] = n[j], n[i]
            perm(n, i + 1)
            n[i], n[j] = n[j], n[i]

perm([1, 2, 3], 0)
```

Comment: In case you don't know, this is a 1 liner in python. itertools.permutations(range(1,4))

Comment: What are you supposed to type at the two `input` calls? What should the output be? If "when i run my algorithm with 'next' it works fine", can we see that working code?

Comment: @Hammer it is my homework and i am not allowed to use itertools :)

Comment: What do you think `factor` returns when `i` is not equal to `n - 1`?

Comment: First of all, it is not good to use type names (`list`) as a variable name

Comment: A bunch of side notes: Don't call a variable `list`; that hides the built-in type. If you don't do that, you can just use `list` instead of `type([])`. To check whether a list is empty, just do `if not lst:`, not `if lst == []`. Finally, `list.pop` returns the popped element, so you can turn the last two lines into `print(list.pop(0))`.

Comment: @abarnert 'n' would be 3 and 'elements' would be 1 2 3 . i want to get 123 132 213 231 ... as result. and the next gives me that answer. :)

Comment: @user3015255: Again, "the next gives me that answer" doesn't tell us anything unless you show us the code that "the next" means.

Comment: And one last note: Normally, a function _either_ mutates its argument and returns `None`, _or_ it returns a new value. Doing both is a recipe for confusion—in fact, exactly the confusion that led you to this error. Your code _is_ correctly mutating `elements` in the recursive call, so it seems like it works… but it doesn't actually return the mutated `elements`.

Comment: OK, I have no idea why you called the working version "my algorithm with 'next'". There is no `next` anywhere in the code, or in the names of the variables, or _anywhere_. How did you expect us to figure out what you meant from that description?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this works:

```
def perm(n, i):
    if i == len(n) - 1:
        print(n)
    else:
        for j in range(i, len(n)):
            n[i], n[j] = n[j], n[i]
            perm(n, i + 1)
            n[i], n[j] = n[j], n[i]
```

Is that you're not returning any value, just printing to the screen. If you want to return a list of all the values that would get printed, you have to (a) build that list, and (b) return that list.

And remember, the base case *and* the recursive case will both have to `return` a list, not just one or the other.

```
def perm(n, i):
    if i == len(n) - 1:
        return [n]
    else:
        results = []
        for j in range(i, len(n)):
            n[i], n[j] = n[j], n[i]
            results.extend(perm(n, i + 1))
            n[i], n[j] = n[j], n[i]
        return results
```

This now returns a list of 6 lists. But it's got *another* problem that you have to fix. Instead of building a new list for each permutation, you're mutating the input list and then returning it. That means you end up with a list of *the same list* 6 times. To fix that, you need to *copy* the list before returning it. So:

```
def perm(n, i):
    if i == len(n) - 1:
        return [n[:]]
    else:
        results = []
        for j in range(i, len(n)):
            n[i], n[j] = n[j], n[i]
            results.extend(perm(n, i + 1))
            n[i], n[j] = n[j], n[i]
        return results
```

Comment: more patient than me :) great answer

Answer (score 2):

Your factor function doesn't always return a value.  A function that ends without returning a value, implicitly returns None.  So list becomes None, which is not sortable.

BTW, you shouldn't use "list" as a variable name - that'll occlude the builtin named list.

Also, that `type(elements) == type([])` - should it be an assert statement?

Comment: Good answer. More specifically, for recursive functions, you need the base case _and_ the recursive case(s) to return a value, not just the base case. In simple cases, this is `return this_function(smaller_args)` instead of just calling `this_function(smaller_args)` and ignoring the result.